# How to get SPSite from a full page url

Tags: c#, sharepoint, url, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom navigation menu for my `SharePoint intranet` web application which is composed of multiple site collections.

The navigation menu is organized differently from the underlying site collections 
(ex. items from two different site collections are in the same navigation section).

Now I need to add security so that menu items are hidden based on permissions.

If one of the menu items has a full url of `"http://intranet.test.com/sites/Accounting/Pages/Welcome.aspx"` then is there a function that I could run from the `SharePoint object model` that would take that `url` and return an `SPSite` object for my site collection at `"http://intranet.test.com/sites/Accounting"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SPSite is quite happy to take the full url and deduce the site from there, nothing you need to do, normal SPSite constructor:

```
using (SPSite mySiteCollection = new SPSite ("http://intranet.test.com/sites/Accounting/Pages/Welcome.aspx"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe I should read the constructor documentation next time.  I always assumed that you needed the exact address.